# Android: JSONException: Value null at VesselList of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android

I'trying to Parsing JSOn object but sometime it runs properly sometime getting followoing error:

> org.json.JSONException: Value null at VesselList of type
>   org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray

```
public void getCompanyDeatails() 
    {
        String strUrl_companyDeatls = "http://103.24.4.60/CLASSNK1/MobileService.svc/Get_Company/Sync_Time/"+strSync_Time+"/Authentication_Token/"+str_Authentication_Token;
        Log.e("strUrl_companyDeatls ", " = " + strUrl_companyDeatls);
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try 
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(strUrl_companyDeatls));
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            if (inputStream != null)
                strResult = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                strResult = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        String jsonStr = strResult;
        Log.e("jsonStr ", " = " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null)
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                String jsonResult = jsonObj.toString().trim();
                Log.e("jsonResult ", " = " + jsonResult);

                JSONObject companyList = jsonObj.getJSONObject("Get_CompanyResult");
                Log.e("companyList ", " = " + companyList.toString());

                JSONArray jarr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("CompanylList");
                Log.e("jarr ", " = " + jarr.toString());

                for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jobCompanyDetails = jarr.getJSONObject(i);

                    str_CompanyId = jobCompanyDetails.getString("Company_ID");
                    str_CompanyName = jobCompanyDetails.getString("Company_Name");

                    Log.e("str_CompanyId ", " = " + str_CompanyId);
                    Log.e("str_CompanyName ", " = " + str_CompanyName);

                    if (dbhelper.isTitleExist(str_CompanyId)) {
                        //Upadte
                        dbhelper.updatedetails(str_CompanyId, str_CompanyName);
                        Log.e("Data updated in ", "Company Table !!");
                    } else {

                        //insert
                        dbhelper.insertCompany(str_CompanyId, str_CompanyName);
                        Log.e("Data inserted in ", "Company Table !!");
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

this is my JSON String

```
{"Get_CompanyResult":{"CompanylList":[{"Company_ID":93,"Company_Name":"SeaChange"},{"Company_ID":97,"Company_Name":"VM 2"}],"Sync_Time":"2015-09-11 12:44:17.533"}}
```

Is this code is right?

Comment: I assume this line? `JSONArray jarr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("CompanylList");`

Comment: Yea i tried this same like JSONArray jarr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("CompanylList"); But i getting error of JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
JSONArray jarr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("CompanylList");
```

line causing issue because `CompanylList` JSONArray is inside `Get_CompanyResult` JSONObject instead of main which is `jsonObj`.

Get `CompanylList` JSONArray from `companyList` JSONObject:

```
JSONArray jarr = companyList.getJSONArray("CompanylList");
```

Comment: I also tried like this JSONArray jarr = companyList.getJSONArray("CompanylList"); the why so getting exception  JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: JSONArray jarr = companyList.getJSONArray("CompanylList"); at this line getting error

Comment: @androidTag: but in posted json in question `CompanylList` is JSONArray. try it using `JSONObject jObject = companyList.getJSONObject("CompanylList");` and share `jObject` string with us

Answer (score 0):

Change your code according to here :

```
public void getCompanyDeatails() {
        String strUrl_companyDeatls = "http://103.24.4.60/CLASSNK1/MobileService.svc/Get_Company/Sync_Time/" + strSync_Time + "/Authentication_Token/" + str_Authentication_Token;
        Log.e("strUrl_companyDeatls ", " = " + strUrl_companyDeatls);
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String strResult = null;
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("strUrl_companyDeatls"));
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

//            strResult = "{\\\"Get_CompanyResult\\\":{\\\"CompanylList\\\":[{\\\"Company_ID\\\":93,\\\"Company_Name\\\":\\\"SeaChange\\\"},{\\\"Company_ID\\\":97,\\\"Company_Name\\\":\\\"VM 2\\\"}],\\\"Sync_Time\\\":\\\"2015-09-11 12:44:17.533\\\"}}";
            String jsonStr=null;
            if (inputStream != null) {
                strResult = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                jsonStr = strResult;
            }

            Log.e("jsonStr ", " = " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                String jsonResult = jsonObj.toString().trim();
                Log.e("jsonResult ", " = " + jsonResult);

                JSONObject companyList = jsonObj.getJSONObject("Get_CompanyResult");
                Log.e("companyList ", " = " + companyList.toString());

                JSONArray jarr = companyList.getJSONArray("CompanylList");
                Log.e("jarr ", " = " + jarr.toString()); // error was here. You need to use companyList json object because it contains company list.

                for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jobCompanyDetails = jarr.getJSONObject(i);

                    String str_CompanyId = jobCompanyDetails.getString("Company_ID");
                    String str_CompanyName = jobCompanyDetails.getString("Company_Name");

                    Log.e("str_CompanyId ", " = " + str_CompanyId);
                    Log.e("str_CompanyName ", " = " + str_CompanyName);

//                    if (dbhelper.isTitleExist(str_CompanyId)) {
//                        //Upadte
//                        dbhelper.updatedetails(str_CompanyId, str_CompanyName);
//                        Log.e("Data updated in ", "Company Table !!");
//                    } else {
//
//                        //insert
//                        dbhelper.insertCompany(str_CompanyId, str_CompanyName);
//                        Log.e("Data inserted in ", "Company Table !!");
//                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Note :**

- There is no need to use nested try and catch.
- For '`strResult = "Did not work!";`', always make sure that every
  exception handled well (at checkpoint of jsonstr is null or not you
  can not identify error occurred at parsing input stream can lead to
  serious bugs).
- HttpClient is deprecated so make sure you use latest version of any
  third party library like **Volley** or **Retrofit** for network
  operation and **GSON** for parsing response. It will minimize your
  efforts.

Thanks.